# 3D annotation for instance segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, annotations, image-segmentation

I'm trying to annotate some data for 3D instance segmentation. While it's fairly straightforward to draw masks for each 2D plane, it's not obvious how to connect the same "instances" together post-annotation (ie. connect the "red" masks together, connect the "blue" masks together) without laboriously making sure the instances are instance-matched (ie. colour-coded to make sure "red" masks always connect with "red" masks).

A naive approach I have thought of is to make many 2D segmentation masks, and calculate the center of mass for each object detected. I can later re-assign the instances based on the closest matching center of mass, but I worry this would inadvertently generate "crossed-over" segmentation instances (illustrated below). What are some high-throughput strategies to generate 3D annotations?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of your 2-d slices could be used as constraints to obtain the optimal 3-d surface, as proposed in [1](https://pyift.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortestpath.html).

However, I think it is easier to generate 3-d labels from markers, such as [2](https://github.com/napari/napari). Its implementation is available in [here](https://pyift.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortestpath.html) (Fill free open an issue if you encounter any problems :P).

Also, the [napari](https://github.com/napari/napari) package could be useful to develop the GUI without much effort.

[1] Grady, Leo. "Minimal surfaces extend shortest path segmentation methods to 3D." IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence 32.2 (2008): 321-334.

[2] Falcão, Alexandre X., and Felipe PG Bergo. "Interactive volume segmentation with differential image foresting transforms." IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging 23.9 (2004): 1100-1108.

Comment: Thanks for the references! However, the image foresting transform is not very intuitive to me. How can this be applied to generate "3-d labels from markers"? In my case, how does it "link" 2D segmentation masks?

Comment: The markers (scribbles) would be labeled pixels in the background and foreground, the remaining pixels in the 3-D volume would be labeled according to the IFT label propagation criterion (min-max distance). So, the segmentation would be achieved from scribbles and from 2-D slices.

Comment: To use 2-D slices (your available masks) as markers, I would get the complement of the dilated mask to obtain the background markers and erode it to obtain the foreground in the 2-D image. Executing the IFT algorithm in the 3-D volume from this will produce the desired results if the boundary is well defined.

Comment: Note that, the dilation and erosion should be done in each 2-D slice individually and then, added to an empty 3-D volume to be used as markers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [3D Slicer's Segment Editor](https://slicer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/image_segmentation.html). It is free, open-source, has many built-in tools, and customizable/extensible in Python or C++ (you can plug in your own segmentation method with minimal effort). To solve a segmentation task, typically you first figure out a good segmentation workflow (what tools to use, in what combination and what parameters) using interactive GUI, then if necessary you can make it semi-automatic or fully automatic using Python scripting.

You can create a segmentation by contouring every image slice, but it would be too tedious. Instead, you can use 3D region growing (Grow from seeds effect) or segment on just a few slices and interpolate between them (Fill between slices effect).